# MVC Model Nullable<short> Issue in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I wonder if somebody can please shed some light on an error I am getting, which is:

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[WebApplication1.Models.Weight]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication1.Models.AddWeightModel'."

AddWeightModel

```
public class AddWeightModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Stone")]
    public Nullable<short> Stone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Pound")]
    public Nullable<short> Pound { get; set; }        
}
```

Weight.cs (Created my ADO.NET Entity Data Model)

```
public partial class Weight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Stone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Pound { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

AccountController

```
public ActionResult RecordCard()
{
    var weightModel = from m in db.Weights where select m;
    return View(weightModel);
}
```

**RecordCard**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@using Shedtember.Models;
@using System.Text;

@model IEnumerable<Shedtember.Models.Weight>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Record Card";

    var message = new StringBuilder();
    message.Append("data: [");

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        message.Append("[Date.UTC(" + @item.Date.Value.ToString("yyyy") + ", " + @item.Date.Value.ToString("mm") + ", " + @item.Date.Value.ToString("dd") + "), " + @item.Stone + "." + @item.Pound + "],");
    }
    message.Append("]");
    message.Replace("],]", "]]");
}
<div class="row">
    <article class="span7">
        <section class="block-indent-1 maxheight">
            <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
            <p>Your progress so far.</p>
            <div id="container" style="min-width: 280px; height: 400px; margin-left:0px"></div>
        </section>
    </article>
    <article class="span5">
        <section class="block-indent-1 divider-left maxheight">
            <h2>Update Profile</h2>
            <p class="text-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>
            <div>
                @Html.Partial("_WeightPartial")
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

It would appear the view is trying to receive data that is different to specified in the Model, but that is not correct, unless I've missed something.

Comment: Could you show the main View RecordCard.cshtml?

Comment: Please see my amended post.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the wrong model type to the view. Your view expects a `AddWeightModel` but you're pasing the `Weight` from your linq query. I'm assuming you meant to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult WeightCard()
{
   var weightModel = (from m in db.Weights select m).First();
   var viewModel = new AddWeightModel
   {
        Stone = weightModel.Stone,
        Pound = weightModel.Pount
   };
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

EDIT: If you're trying to pass multiple items to the view, you could change your view to use:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.AddWeightModel>
```

And then pass a collection:

```
var viewModel = (from m in db.Weights select new AddWeightModel
   {
        Stone = m.Stone,
        Pound = m.Pount
   }).ToList();
return View(weightModel);
```

Note that the snippet is untested and you'll need to change your view logic to iterate the collection.

Comment: there is no where clause multiple objects will be returned

Comment: Good point to add! He's still trying to pass the wrong model type, though.

Comment: I need multiple records as I'm generating a dynamic graph.

Comment: then change you model type in view

Comment: The RecordCard.cshtml needs a full list from Weights, but in RecordCard.cshtml there is also a _WeightPartial.cshtml file which is a form used to add weights using AddWeightModel does this clarify things.

Comment: How are you calling the partial? If you're just passing an item from the model from the RecordCard view which, I'm assuming, is a collection of Weights, then you'll get that exception. You'll need to either update the partial to use a Weight or change how you call the partial.

Comment: I'm using @Html.Partial("_WeightPartial") to call the Form.

Comment: Just saw your update. If this partialview doesn't need any data from the view (it looks like it's purpose is to add an item to the database), you could try passing a null model. Something like `@Html.Partial("_WeightPartial", null)`

Comment: Er, I meant `new AddWeightModel()` instead of `null`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not enough caffeine in me!

Comment: Nice one Bill, the page opens, now I need to get the form to add a record to the Weights table and reload the page on successful add.

Answer (score -1):

you need to execute the query by using `ToList()` if multiple rows are expected and needed in view and use `FirstOrDefault()` if one object is needed in view:

```
var weightModel = (from m in db.Weights
                   select m).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
    return View(weightModel);
```

**View:**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Weight
```

For Multiple objects:

```
var weightModel = (from m in db.Weights
                       select m).ToList();
        return View(weightModel);
```

**View:**

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.Weight>
```

If you are using `AddWeightModel` then:

```
(from m in db.Weights select new AddWeightModel
   {
        Stone = m.Stone,
        Pound = m.Pount
   }).ToList();
```

**View:**

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.AddWeightModel>
```

Comment: View expect type AddWeightModel

Comment: i edited OP needs to Pass actually Weight model nor AddWeight

Comment: No AddWeight is ĥis view model with validations. Also am not the down voter.

Comment: ok then my mistake i did'nt understood right. but added that as well

Comment: Maybe 'm going about this all wrong, but I need a list of weights for a graph from db.Weights on the left of the page and then I'm using a form on the right to add extra data to the Weights table, as the page posts the graph should update.

Comment: why are you using seperate model for adding weights you have model class weights already you should be using that instead of creating a new

Comment: I'm new to ASP.NET, trying to figure things out. I just want to add a record to the existing Weight table and when the page refreshes, so will the graph.

Comment: in the add action save entry in db and return updated list to the view to make graph

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52229/discussion-between-iggyweb-and-ehsan-sajjad)